# How to make MUI Fade fade in on render?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using the Fade component of Material UI as part of a stepper. I want the steps to fade in on render. How can I make it work? [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-un2q4)

```
function getStepContent(step) {
  switch (step) {
    case 0:
      return (
        <Fade in>
          <div>'Step 1: Select campaign settings...'</div>
        </Fade>
      );
    case 1: ...
    default:
      return "Unknown step";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a separate component for the Fade components, that would begin with the `in` prop set to false and then immediately set it to true using some state and a `useEffect`:

```
function CustomFade(props) {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setShow(true);
  }, []);

  return <Fade in={show}>{props.children}</Fade>;
}
```

Also, you have to add the `key` prop to the `CustomFade`, so React remounts it.

```
function getStepContent(step) {
  switch (step) {
    case 0:
      return (
        <CustomFade key="step0">
          <div>'Step 1: Select campaign settings...'</div>
        </CustomFade>
      );
    case 1: ...
    default:
      return "Unknown step";
  }
}
```